# How do you capitalize the first word and every word after a period?

Tags: python

So far I'm able to capitalize the first word of the sentence, but I need every first letter after a period to be capitalized. 
This is what I have:

```
def main():
    input1 = input('Enter your input here: ')
    capitalize = str.capitalize(input1)
    print("The capitalized version:", capitalize)

main()
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [Sentence Case](http://packages.python.org/tl.rename/tl/rename/case.html#sentence-case) of the [rename package](http://packages.python.org/tl.rename/index.html).

```
>>> from tl.rename.case import transform_sentence_case
>>> transform_sentence_case(['foo bar baz', 'FOO bar. baz Asdf'])
['Foo bar baz', 'Foo bar. Baz asdf']
```

Or you could use a regex...

```
\.\s*([a-z])
```

Captialise the `$1` capturing group.

Answer (score -2):

Just use .title() method of a string (either ASCII or Unicode is fine).

For your instance:

```
>>> 'Enter your input here: '.title()
'Enter Your Input Here: '
```

Comment: That doesn't actually do what the OP wants.